# Create a list from another list in python

Tags: python

```
def other(A,B):
    sorted_List = sorted(A, reverse=True)[:3]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if(A[i] != sorted_List[0] or A[i] != sorted_List[1] or A[i] != 
        sorted_List[2]):
            B.append(A[i])
    return B
```

so when I try to print the new array it gives me an none result

Comment: Because `return` is missing and there is no proper indentation in the function.

Comment: You are talking about a `list`. An array is a different data type in Python.

Comment: What new array? `others` is never used again, and you modify the second argument `B` in place.

Comment: I edit the code sorry about the mistake that I made while copy pasting

Comment: I think others function doesn't require parameter B.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show a `return` in the function. Not include it will not give you any result when calling the function. Also, as said by Celius, the indentation of the function is incorrect, the "body" of the function should be one tab to the right.

Also, a comment, you declared `x = len(A)` but you did not use it. You could change `range(len(A))` to `range(x)`.

Comment: I edited the code but still it only returned the first element that did not match the condition Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is the IF. You are using or, so the only possibility that the condition is not true is that the sorted_List has all the same three values and the A[i] element is equal to that value. Is that the idea? Using A = [1,2,4,3] and B = [4,3,2], what would you expect to be the result? I used it and the result is [4,3,2,1,2,4,3], that's because I think there's something with the if